# XMLHttpRequest POST is canceled

Tags: php, javascript, xmlhttprequest

I am using XMLHttpRequest in my site, and I have only one problem. When I try to login the post gets canceled, but it only happens with this action in the whole site.

This is my code:

```
var hr = new XMLHttpRequest();
var url = "logIn.php";

var email = document.getElementById("input-username").value;
var password = document.getElementById("input-login-password").value;

var vars = "email=" + email + "&password=" + password;


hr.open("POST", url, true);
hr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "x-www-form-urlencoded");

hr.onreadystatechange = function() {
    var return_data = hr.responseText;
    if(hr.readyState == 4 && hr.status == 200) {
        isLoggedIn(return_data);
    }else{
        if (hr.readyState == 4 && hr.status == 400){
            alert('problem logging in');
        }
    }
}
hr.send(vars);
```

My post info:

```
Request URL:http://beta.amanha.eu/logIn.php
Request Headersview source
Content-type:x-www-form-urlencoded
Origin:http://beta.amanha.eu
Referer:http://beta.amanha.eu/?
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.17 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/24.0.1312.56 Safari/537.17
Request Payload
email=a@a.com&password=12345
```

Can this be a problem in the php file?

Answer (score 0):

You are setting an invalid `Content-Type`. The correct type is `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`.